# Regex help in Python for selectively removing parentheses from Mathematical expressions

Tags: python, regex

Here are some sample inputs:

```
x(n)+(y(n)+1)*n
x(n(a,b),a,b)+2^(y(n(a,b)+a+b)+1)
x(n)+(y(n)/(N(n)))
```

and I want their corresponding outputs to be:

```
x[n]+(y[n]+1)*n
x[n[a,b],a,b]+2^(y[n[a,b]+a+b]+1)
x[n]+(y[n]/(N[n]))
```

I wrote the following code, but it is not giving any output:

```
def replace():
    string='x(n)+2^(y(n)+1)'
    print re.sub(r'/(\w+)\(([^()]+)\)/', '\1[\2]', string)
```

Comment: Do you consider using [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex)? If yes, just use `r'\b[a-zA-Z]\w*(\((?>[^()]|(?1))*\))'` regex and replace the `(` with `[` and `)` with `]` in the replacement.

Comment: Python regexes shouldn't be enclosed in slashes.  Try `r'(\w+)\(([^()]+)\)'`

Answer (score 2):

The [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) supports recursion. You can install it and use the following code:

```
>>> import regex
>>> p = regex.compile(r'\b[a-zA-Z]\w*(\((?>[^()]|(?1))*\))')
>>> s = "x(n)+(y(n)+1)*n\nx(n(a,b),a,b)+2^(y(n(a,b)+a+b)+1)\nx(n)+(y(n)/(N(n)))"
>>> print(p.sub(lambda m: m.group().replace("(", "[").replace(")", "]"), s))
x[n]+(y[n]+1)*n
x[n[a,b],a,b]+2^(y[n[a,b]+a+b]+1)
x[n]+(y[n]/(N[n]))
```

The [regex demo is available here](https://regex101.com/r/oJ4jK7/1).

The `\b[a-zA-Z]\w*` matches an identifier-like sequence (a whole word starting with a letter and then followed with optional word characters (digits, letters or an underscore) and `(\((?>[^()]|(?1))*\))` matches nested `(...()...)` sequences thanks to the subroutine call `(?1)` (that recurses, repeats, the pattern in Group 1).